# 123 ERROR_INVALID_NAME after activate Wave audio liverecorder

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using the `wave audio component` in my project and I run into a problem that I am unable to resolve.

I am using Delphi XE 5 and my operating system is Windows 8. When I am trying to the run the project and active the liveaudio recorder on Windows 7, I got this: `error Exception EOSError in module Chatproject.exe at 00029633. System Error. Code: 123. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`. But its working normal on Windows 8,. I tried to debug and figure out the problem I got this error message when I am activating the recorder

Update of the question :

i debugged each of sendtocl , sendbuffer ,buffer^, buffersize and here is result in the image ,, but i have no idea  how to fix sendbuffer and buffer^ and sendtocl

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sZ05.jpg

Comment: Which line is causing the exception? Surely you can narrow it down to something more than "somewhere in these dozens of lines of code there's a problem".

Comment: i edit the question and added when the error happen i am still trying to figure out the exact problem .

Comment: Better. Do you have the source file where `TLiveAudioRecorder` is located (presumably `WaveRecorders.pas`)? If so, find the property setter for the `Active` property, and set a breakpoint there, and then run again. What happens when you're setting `Active := True` in that code?

Comment: i found the exact line of both error its on the client send buffer code but i have no idea how to fix it the exact error has been added in the question appreciate your help

Comment: Ok. Now set a breakpoint on that line of code, and run until the breakpoint is hit, and then put the mouse pointer over `sendtoc1`. What does the popup that appears tell you that `sendtoc1` is at that point? What about `Buffer`? We can't step through the code for you, because we don't have all of the components you're using, the exact hardware and drivers, or the rest of the code for your app, so you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: You've got to learn to use a debugger. Drop everything and learn that skill.

Comment: i updated the question i think all problem with send buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four references to sendtocl:

```
#56:     sendtocl: TIdUDPClient;

#235:  if sendtocl.active then
#236:    sendtocl.SendBuffer(RawToBytes(Buffer^, Buffersize))

#260: sendtocl.Broadcast(usertype.Text, 12000);
```

It should be getting created when the form is created, assuming it's a component dropped on the form. But for whatever reason, it isn't instantiated at some point.

This is consistent with the exception message you're getting.

The ERROR_INVALID_NAME is probably pointing to an invalid URI, path, or filename -- it's entirely possible that it's valid in Win 8 but not Win 7. So when you try to invoke .Active, it fails. But why sendtocl woudl be set to NIL doesn't make sense. Mabye the exception is on the SendBuffer method?

As Ken suggests, you just need to go in with the debugger and figure out what's going on. I'm not sure there's much more us "out here" can do for you other than comment on how the code appears.

Comment: @David is right, that's for sure a `nil` pointer that is going to be dereferenced.

Comment: If sendtocl is nil, then the call to SendBuffer is definitely not going to work properly. I think you need to spend more time learning to use the debugger.

Comment: sendtocl is nil Yes i already update the question any help to fix it ?

Comment: Question updated with some result hope it helps to fix  this problem it takes long time to try to find the nil pointer

Comment: It doesn't help that you removed your source code. That image says nothing useful.

Comment: The thing you're missing that's the most obvious question is this: if this is a component you're dropping on the form, it gets auto-created when the form is created. So why is it NIL at some later point? It shouldn't be.  I'd delete the one on the form and create it in the code. Then you can trace what happens to it as you step through your code with the debugger.